# What exactly does ACL mean? (Sharepoint)

Tags: asp.net, security, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We talk about ACL in SharePoint and that document library inherits ACL by default, and we may chose to have separate ACL for document library, etc.

So, when we talk about ACL, are we referring to List of Groups/Users we navigate to Manage Permission link on site or library?

I tried searching on web but couldn't find any insight on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ACL - Access Control List.

Ok, that's not very helpful. It changes on context, but basically it's the list of permissions for an asset that allows you to assign rights to users and groups of users (and in stranger cases machines and other non-human things).

In your case it's the Windows groups, and individual users that may access Sharepoint, and the permissions for those users (Can read, can upload a file, etc.)

Comment: Cool Thanks. I had some idea, but thought it's always good to ask. It makes more sense now.

Comment: @blowdart how do i get a list of users having access to a particular file or list in sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

It means Access Control List.  It's the list of users who may access a resource, and the term isnt Sharepoint specific- we use the same term for Windows permissions.  In Sharepoint, it's the list of users permissioned to access/modify/etc the site, which by default is the same list allowed to act on the document library.

Answer (score 0):

ACL = Access Control List. It lists subjects (users) that can access a resource or an object (file/wiki/document/etc)

Answer (score 0):

I believe an ACL is a set of mapping information for the relationships between Users and Permissions.
When an ACL is assoicated with a Security Object (List, DocLib, Site...), and when you try to visit the Security Object, SharePoint will look through the ACL to see if you are within the ACL and what Permissions you have. Then, SharePoint knows weather to show you the Security Object or not.